# What is a Reversible Number™

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles, and the likewise inspired [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.</sub>

---

If a number conforms to a special rule, I call it a Reversible Number™. If it doesn't, it might be an Irreversible Number™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Reversible number™ | Non reversible number™ |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 213 |
| 348 | 537 |
| 761 | 879 |
| 2485 | 2639 |
| 4762 | 4519 |
| 7249 | 7564 |
| 16983 | 16938 |
| 52769 | 85372 |
| 89572 | 92134 |
| 215743 | 281397 |
| 634927851 | 564173982 |

Here is a CSV version:

```
Reversible number™,Non reversible number™
123,213
348,537
761,879
2485,2639
4762,4519
7249,7564
16983,16938
52769,85372
89572,92134
215743,281397
634927851,564173982
```

These are not the only examples of Reversible Numbers™ (or Irreversible Numbers™), more can be found.

What rule defines Reversible Numbers™? What separates Reversible Numbers™ and Irreversible Numbers™ from all other numbers?

Comment: "What separates Reversible Numbers™ and Irreversible Numbers™ from all other numbers?" - are you saying Irreversible Numbers™ are not all numbers that aren't Reversible Numbers™? If so, what are an examples of numbers which are both not Reversible™ and not Irreversible™?

Comment: @boboquack My first hint is probably going to be some numbers that are neither, but for now I can say that, when reversed, a Reversible Number™ will become another Reversible Number™, but an Irreversible Number™ will become neither.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reversible:

> A Reversible Number is one where, when traced on a keypad, no line segment passes through an existing vertex on the path. If the number is flipped, that is still true.
>
>  [image]
>
>  Given the [final tracing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkqqB.png) and the guarantee that it is reversible, you would be able to figure out the original number (or its reverse).

Irreversible:

> An Irreversible Number is one where a line segment passes through an existing vertex. This happens when 3 digits are in a line (horizontally, vertically, or diagonally) and it starts in the middle and then goes to each end. (In shorter numbers, this happens immediately; in longer numbers such as the bottom left, it visits another digit in between)
>
>  [image]
>
>  Given the [final tracings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZbK8.png), you would NOT be able to figure out the original number because there are many possibilities.

Neither:

> I imagine a "neither" would be one with the same number repeated, e.g. 5441. No line segment crosses through a vertex; however, you would not be able to figure out that there is more than one 4. Or perhaps another example would be 13, which passes through the 2, but the 2 is not an existing vertex. So it is neither reversible or irreversible

Comment: Interesting indeed. But it's kind of ruled out by [this comment](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60493/what-is-a-reversible-number#comment184912_60493).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir ah I missed the part about it becoming "neither." Still, I think I am on the right track... unfortunately have to go catch my train now so I'm sure some genius on here will find it before I get another chance!

Comment: @frabjrew You are certainly on the right track! Just not *quite* there yet :)

Comment: @DqwertyC updated my guess... not completely happy with the "Neither" explanation, but it now fits everything!

Comment: @frabjrew Your last sentence of the neither explanation is essentially right. The puzzle was built around Android phone lockscreens, so a "neither" would be a order that couldn't be a valid lock screen password.